# ODE featuring product of derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I consider an ODE of the form

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}U(u)}{\mathrm{d}u} \frac{\mathrm{d}V(v)}{\mathrm{d}v} = f(u, v).  $$

The function $f$ is known, and the goal is to find $U$ and $V$, assuming that any initial or boundary conditions which turn out to be necessary have been specified. This equation arises when trying to find the Weyl rescaling upon coordinates $u$ and $v$ leading to the 2D line element
$$ ds^2 = -f^{-1}(u, v)  du dv.$$

Despite its apparent simplicitly I find I do not know how to solve or even classify this system: it is not a PDE since $U$ and $V$ are respectively independent of $v$ and $u$; it does not obviously separate into a pair of coupled ODEs, etc.

Anyway, I would like to solve this system, presumably numerically. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit:

It has been pointed out that the form given implies $f(u,v) = g(u) h(v)$. Thus the problem separates into that of solving two coupled ODEs: $\frac{dU}{du} = -\lambda g(u)$ and $\frac{dV}{dv} = -\lambda h(v)$. Therefore, the remaining substance of the question is to find $g$ and $h$.

Comment: What does $f$ look like?  In order to get a solution it would need to be split into a product of a function of $u$ and a function of $v$ to be consistent with the LHS.

Comment: I think that RHS should have the form $f(u,v)=g(u)h(v)$, am I right?

Comment: I suppose it must have that form, but in the cases I have in mind $f$ is supplied in such a way that this is not otherwise obvious.

Comment: Unless $f(u,v)=g(u)h(v)$, there is no such $U(u)$ and $V(v)$ satisfying the equation. As @Paul said, the solution approach would be to split $f$ and solve for $U$ and $V$ separately. If you can't split $f$, there is no solution.

Comment: I have edited to account for this.

Comment: I'm not sure of the meaning of $\lambda$ here. Furthermore, finding $h$ and $g$ is quite a broad question, and only demands some algebra. It's not something you can calculate numerically, though. However, if you have $f(u,v)=\exp(u+v)$, for example, you know $g(u) = \exp u$ and $h(v) = \exp v$. If you have $f(u,v) = u+v$, there are no $g$ and $h$ and, therefore, no $U$ and $V$.

Comment: Finding $g$ and $h$ is going to require the actual function form of $f$, as two-variable functions are not in general separable. Also you need a $^{-1}$ on one of those $\lambda$s

Answer (score 2):

$$  f(u,v) = \frac{\text dU(u)}{\text du} \frac{\text dV(v)}{\text dv} = g_1(u)g_2(v) $$

Thus, if $f(u,v)$ is not expressible as $f_1 (u) f_2 (v)$ for some $f_1,f_2$, then the equation is not possible. If it is, then simply solve the two equations

$$ f_1(u) = g_1(u) \\ f_2(v) = g_2(v) $$

Comment: When you say *then the equation is not possible*, are you referring to a lack of known methods for finding a solution, or that the equation does not have solutions? At a glance I suspect the former, but I would rather not assume.

Comment: @Galen It is the latter. In order to write $f$ as a product of $U'(u)V'(v)$, we must be able to (1) write $f$ as a product of $f_1(u)f_2(v)$, and (2) we must have $f_1 = U'$ and $f_2 = V'$ for some $U,V$. Of course, if $f$ satisfies (1) but we just don't know how to find $f_1,f_2$, that does not preclude any solution.